# Bit of Help Porting this tutorial

Tags: android, opengl-es, porting

I'm trying to use the code in [this tutorial](http://nehe.gamedev.net/article/using_gluunproject/16013/), but its in the wrong language (OPEN-GL) so i'm porting it into OPENGL-ES as best I can. This is what I have so far:

```
public void coordinates (GL10 gl, int x, int y, int width, int height){
        int[] viewport = new int[4];
        gl.glGetIntegerv(GL11.GL_VIEWPORT, viewport, 0);
        int[] modelview = new int[16];
        gl.glGetIntegerv(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, modelview, 0);
        int[] projection = new int[16];
        gl.glGetIntegerv(GL11.GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX, projection, 0);

        sety = viewport[3] - sety;
}
```

Got a bit thrown by the glReadPixel command because it doesn't accept this

```
gl.glReadPixels(setx, sety, 1, 1, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT, &setz);
```

Error states that GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT and &setz can't be resolved. What is the OPENGL-ES alternative?

Also the last part of the tutorial, step 5, is that a whole new method or a compilation of the whole tutorial?

NOTE: setx and sety are private floats called at the top of my code

EDIT: I'm also having trouble with the gluUnProject command it seems to require more values than the opengl version in the tutorial.

(in opengl-es)

```
 GLU.gluUnProject(winX, winY, winZ, model, modelOffset, project, projectOffset, view, viewOffset, obj, objOffset)
```

(and in the tutorial)

```
gluUnProject( winX, winY, winZ, modelview, projection, viewport, &posX, &posY, &posZ);
```

EDIT:

Okay I think I've pretty much solved my own question but I'm still having problems.

```
gl.glReadPixels
```

requires these variables

```
glReadPixels(int, int, int, int, int, int, Buffer)
```

Which is fine but

```
GLU.gluUnproject
```

Requires the x coordinate (returned as a buffer by readpixels) to be float.

Also in the NeHe tutorial UnProject returns three floats but here it seems to only leave room for one so I have no idea how to get the variables. This is my current glUnproject code which doesn't match the accepted layout yet.

```
GLU.gluUnProject(setx, newsety, setz, modelview, 0, projection, 0, viewport, 0, posx, 0, posy, 0, posz, 0);
```

these arguments are as such

```
 (float, float, buffer, int[], int, int[], int, int[], int, float, int, float, int, float, int)]
```

When they should be

```
(float, float, float, float[], int, float[], int, int[], int, float[], int)
```

EDIT:

Right I decided I could do away with the readpixel command because my game is 2D and setting z to 0 should work OK

so the buffer problem is gone

I changed some of my variables to floats and GLU.gluUnProject now returns no errors.  I still don't quite know how to return the posx, posy, posz variables however.

Here is my code as it stands.

```
 public void Vector3 (GL11 gl, int x, int y){
        int[] viewport = new int[4];
        float[] modelview = new float[16];
        float[] projection = new float[16];
        float winx, winy, winz;
        float posx, posy, posz;
        float[] Vector3 = new float[3];

        gl.glGetIntegerv(GL11.GL_VIEWPORT, viewport, 0);
        gl.glGetFloatv(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, modelview, 0);
        gl.glGetFloatv(GL11.GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX, projection, 0);

        winx = setx;
        winy = viewport[3] - sety;
        winz = 0;

        GLU.gluUnProject(winx, winy, winz, modelview, 0, projection, 0,     viewport, 0, Vector3, 0);

        return Vector3(posx, posy, posz);


    }
```

setx, sety, setz are global variables and the return Vector3(posx, posy, posz); line currently returns errors.

Your help would be appreciated thankyou.

EDIT: Okay Think I got it

Here is some code (I included the motion event method because that is where the problem currently is and the draw method to give some context)

```
public synchronized void randomMethod(MotionEvent event){
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
        setx = event.getX();
        sety = event.getY();
        Vector3(null);
        }
    }

    public void Vector3 (GL11 gl){
        int[] viewport = new int[4];
        float[] modelview = new float[16];
        float[] projection = new float[16];
        float winx, winy, winz;
        float[] Vector3 = new float[3];

        gl.glGetIntegerv(GL11.GL_VIEWPORT, viewport, 0);
        gl.glGetFloatv(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, modelview, 0);
        gl.glGetFloatv(GL11.GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX, projection, 0);

        winx = setx;
        winy = viewport[3] - sety;
        winz = 0;


        GLU.gluUnProject(winx, winy, winz, modelview, 0, projection, 0, viewport, 0, Vector3, 0);

        posx = Vector3[1];
        posy = Vector3[2];
        posz = Vector3[3];


    }



 @Override
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
         gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT |
            GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

             gl.glLoadIdentity();
             gl.glPushMatrix();
    gl.glTranslatef(posx, posy, posz);
    gl.glScalef(100, 100, 0);
    square.draw(gl);        
    gl.glPopMatrix();
 }
```

My error log shows

```
07-30 10:41:03.220: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(340): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
07-30 10:41:03.270: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(340): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-30 10:41:03.270: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(340):     at android.app.ui.GLSurfaceRenderer.Vector3(GLSurfaceRenderer.java:51)
07-30 10:41:03.270: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(340):     at android.app.ui.GLSurfaceRenderer.randomMethod(GLSurfaceRenderer.java:40)
07-30 10:41:03.270: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(340):     at android.app.ui.Practice.onTouchEvent(Practice.java:41)
07-30 10:41:03.270: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(340):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2064)
07-30 10:41:03.270: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(340):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1643)
07-30 10:41:03.270: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(340):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1690)
07-30 10:41:03.270: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(340):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-30 10:41:03.270: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(340):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-30 10:41:03.270: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(340):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4310)
07-30 10:41:03.270: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(340):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-30 10:41:03.270: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(340):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
 07-30 10:41:03.270: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(340):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
 07-30 10:41:03.270: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(340):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
 07-30 10:41:03.270: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(340):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I have a hunch that the problem may be caused by the way i've called Vector3 in randomMethod, but I can't think how else I could achieve the same thing (maybe its the null argument).

Comment: m working over it, m new on open-gl but learn lots, thanks man

Answer (score 2):

It is your null argument.

Vector3 is expecting an instance of GL11 but you are providing it with null, this means that when it comes to

```
gl.glGetIntegerv(GL11.GL_VIEWPORT, viewport, 0);
gl.glGetFloatv(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, modelview, 0);
gl.glGetFloatv(GL11.GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX, projection, 0);
```

`gl = NULL` and you get a ***null pointer***.

If you are doing this so you can purely get a Z coordinate then you are going to have to place this method somewhere where is has access to GL11